# Pre-defined function to format strings in Python to be used in SQL

Tags: python, mysql

First of all i'm French so if you see any mistakes in my message, don't hesitate to tell me ! :)

Here's my problematic : I'm currently making a Python function, to build SQL requests, inserting in my database a large string (the HTML code to a webpage).

As you may know, SQL have some requirements regarding the string you use. For example you can't use `' I'm a developper'` sentence because of the ' ' ' thing.

Do you know if any pre-defined function exist to modify a chain to make sure I could use it in an SQL Request ?

I'm also asking that because I don't know all the requirements to a string to be interpreted without a problem.

I hope I've been clear, let me know if I havent !
Have a nice day.

EDIT : I'm on Python 3.4.3
EDIT2: I'm using MySQL

Comment: if you are using mysql you may be able to use the `escape_string` function.

Comment: What module are you using to insert the text into the database?
And if you want to insert text with single quotes, you can simply use double quotes in python...
`"I'm a developer"`

Comment: @JanZeiseweis The 'I'm a developper' thing was an exemple, I have to import hundreds of HTML pages, with a lot a ' and ".
I'm using mysql.connector to build and send my requests.

Comment: which DB engine are you using?

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: see my answer. You only need to use escape_string which is included with your python connector

Comment: I'm currently trying but getting "'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'escape_string'" every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty broad question and I think you should refine it.

As for good practices with SQL in general you first need to :

- Make sure you are using the proper library (and the most up to date) depending or your situation (MySQL, Oracle, SQLite, etc.)
- Escape string. The library usually has a function for this. You can also use `format` or `%`.
- Test, unit tests or at least manual one... What I usually do to prototype is to first generate the SQL statement and print it. Then I copy this statement and test it directly into SQL command line. This way you're sure it's working for SQL. Then from there, you'll need to escape special characters with `\`. Second points would cover that though.
- Finally you want to wrap your code in a `try / catch` statement so you can control failures.
- If it still does not work, a good, somewhat hacky, `.replace()` will. An example would be: `.replace("'", "\'")`. Make sure you can standardized your input.

Edit:
The length of your statement does not matter if you cover edge cases.

Edit 2 :
Use `MySQLdb.escape_string(statement)` if you're using mysql-python 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-cext-escape-string.html

Comment: I guess my question should be like : 
I want to put a string on my database via a SQL request but I don't necessarily know all the requirements to do it without error, and i'm sure the code of an HTML page with lots of ' and " won't work. So I want to automatize the format of the strings with a function.

Comment: As i said, the library you're using to make sql calls has the function to escape string. Use this and you'll be able to push any string into the DB. Which DB are you using?

Comment: escape string will cover that for you. Try it. Check also sanitize.

Comment: It gets very inventive with the naming
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to escape the character and this should work.

```
my_sql_string = 'this my \'word\' with escaped character'
```

Also, you should probably look into "text" object from sqlalchemy: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#using-textual-sql

Comment: Yup, but my variables contain thousands of characters, and I have hundreds of variables so i'm looking for a way to automatize the thing a little bit.